# What's the Python analogue of npm link?

Tags: python, pip

If you have the source for a Node project, the command `npm link` installs it in such a way that any changes you make apply everywhere without you having to reinstall.

> npm link is designed to install a development package and see the changes in real time without having to keep re-installing it.

https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-developers.html#link-packages

Is there a analogue for Python projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `pip install -e .` or `python setup.py develop`

See http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#editable-installs

Comment: This is actually (unfortunately) not equivalent at all.